# crossplatform mysql_install_db script in mysql 5.5.34 on Windows

Tags: mysql, database, installation

I downloaded mysql-5.5.34-win32.zip and found out there is mysql_install_db.pl script.
However mysql 5.5 documentation says:

> mysql_install_db is a shell script and is available only on Unix
>   platforms. (As of MySQL 5.6, mysql_install_db is a Perl script and can
>   be used on any system with Perl installed.)

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html

mysql-5.5.34-linux2.6-i686.tar.gz archive contains shell version of mysql_install_db script.

Why does mysql 5.5.34 for Windows contain this script? Is it an issue in 5.5 documentation?

**UPD 1:**

I found several comments in bugs.mysql.com which confirm that this perl script is useless on Windows:

> I am not sure if this script is intended to be executed on Windows at all. Our manual clearly says: "It is unnecessary to run the mysql_install_db script that is used on Unix."

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52183

or

> mysql_install_db is not supported on Windows and scheduled for removal from our Windows packages.

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35105

But is there any official comment that this script really useless on Windows?